# Error 1064 de MySQL - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de encriptar y desencriptar pero no me funciona la desencriptación,
presento un problema de sintaxis según el mensaje de error 1064, pero he chequeado varias veces la línea y no se que podrá estar mal.

Esta es mi línea de encriptación y funciona:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES('admin2',AES_ENCRYPT('admin2', '508f06b2c59c1088669292ca894c0522e59df33eeff56001f46d3c30676cca71'),'admin2','admin2',32,'Playing a sport');
```

Esta es mi línea de desencriptación y no funciona:

```
SELECT username, CAST (AES_DECRYPT(passw, '508f06b2c59c1088669292ca894c0522e59df33eeff56001f46d3c30676cca71') AS VARCHAR(250)) FROM users;
```

He intentado con CHAR a ver si de pronto funcionaba pero no.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.
PDT: Utiliza Heidi como SGBD

Comment: Por favor delimita que usas ¿MySQL o MariaDB? y que versión en específico

Comment: para que usas el cast cuando desencriptas

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que la marcara como aceptada y dieras un voto, la pregunta nueva que haces hazla como una nueva pregunta, no aquí mismo, de esta forma va a estar visible a todos los miembros de la comunidad

Comment: Ah okey, gracias

Comment: Pero si tienes idea más o menos de como ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encriptar debes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
insert into tabla values(aes_encrypt('texto a encriptar','clave'));
```

El primer parámetro es el texto que deseas encriptar y el segundo es la clave con la que vas a encriptar ese texto.

Para desencriptar sería:

```
select aes_decrypt('texto encriptado','clave') from tabla;
```

Donde el primer parámetro es el texto encriptado y el segundo es la clave que se uso para encriptar dicho texto, y que tambien sirve para desencriptar el texto.